# keyboard strokes are coming in Hindi(asian language)

Tags: modeling, uv

in spite of having qwerty keyboard , while searching using space bar string what i'm typing is displayed in hindi language , so thats why it is not able to search item for me.

Comment: I think the keyboard is activated to hindi (asian language) screenshot plz

Comment: While blender can use translated UI text, I think the text input you refer to is coming from a system keyboard setting.